# Choice of Time Series Models for Forecasting Data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, model-selection, model-comparison

I have a question that to most readers here probably think is fairly simple to answer, but never the less, out of curiosity I'd like to ask:

Given a time series, yt, which is stationary (say the log returns of a stock x): if this series is best explained by an ARMA(2,1) model in sample, would it make sense to compare its out of sample performance to that of an MA(1) or AR(1) model to the same data set?

The reason I'm asking is because I have heard that some simpler models often times perform better than more complicated ones.

Please view sample code here: This code compares the MSE from an out of sample forecast for an AR(1) model and a Best Fit ARMA.

```
require(tseries)
require(quantmod)
require(forecast)
getSymbols("AAPL", from = "2015-01-01", to = "2020-01-01")
plot.ts(AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted)

log_returns <- diff(log(AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted))
log_returns <- log_returns[2:length(log_returns)] #remove 1 NA

plot.ts(log_returns)
adf.test(log_returns) #stationary

#training set
log_training_set <- log_returns[1: round(0.7 * length(log_returns), digits = 0)]
log_test_set <- log_returns[(length(log_training_set) + 1) : length(log_returns)]

#fit models to training data
best_fit_arma <- auto.arima(log_training_set); summary(best_fit_arma) #ARMA(3,3)
ar_one <- arima(log_training_set, order = c(1,0,0)); summary(ar_one) #AR(1)

#forecast n periods ahead
best_fit_arma_forecast <- forecast(best_fit_arma,h = length(log_test_set))
ar_one_forecast <- forecast(ar_one, h = length(log_test_set))

#MSE Function

# write a function to compute the mean squared error
mean_squared_error <- function(y_true, y_pred){
  
  #calculate the reciprocal for multiplying with the sum of squared errors
  reciprocal <- 1 / length(y_true)
  
  #sum of squared errors
  sum_squared_errors <- sum((y_true - y_pred)^2)
  
  #return mse
  mean_squared_error <- reciprocal * sum_squared_errors
  return(mean_squared_error)
  
}

#Retrieve MSE for each Model
arma_mse <- mean_squared_error(y_true = log_test_set, y_pred = best_fit_arma_forecast$mean)
ar_one_mse <- mean_squared_error(y_true = log_test_set, y_pred = ar_one_forecast$mean)

arma_mse
ar_one_mse
```

In this example, the AR(1) performs better out of sample as measured by MSE. My question here is  though, can this comparison of models even be justified? Considering the residuals from the AR(1) process likely do not resemble white noise, can this model even be used to forecast? Thanks in advance and please let me know if I can be more specific.

Comment: I think its pretty well accepted that you should use your model to predict a hold out data set say the last 12 months for monthly data. Which is a out of sample data set since you build your model without the hold out data set.

Comment: @user54285 thanks for the comment. Right, it is common practice to keep a hold out data set for prediction. However, my question was concerned with the choice of model for the prediction of out of sample data

Comment: I thought you already knew which ones you wanted to test. I guess my suggestion would be to take the (2,0,1) arima model and the (1,0,0) and (0,0,1) models and predict the hold out data set. Then see which one actually predicts better. Note that while it is often stated that simpler models predict better than more complex ones I have never seen a justification in practice or theory given for this. So I don't know its actually true. But it is commonly said.

Comment: Thank you @user54285. What I have done is use an MA(1), AR(1), ARMA(1,1) and the best fit ARIMA(p,d,q) for predicting a held out test set. The simpler models did perform fairly well, but the best fit ARIMA(p,d,q) had better performance across all 300 assets. My reason for posting was due to the fact that I wasn't certain if it is common practice/acceptable to even compare the above models if they don't all fit the data.

Comment: A lot of the time series literature I have seen, like ARIMA itself, is very practical. It deals less than statistical theory than other methods do. For instance it is suggested that you run multiple models and average them. But if there is statistical theory behind this I have never seen it. Similarly they tend to pay less attention to violations of the assumptions then other methods in my experience. But that is just my experience, others may see it differently.